# Select two rows into two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, rows, multiple-columns

I have SQL query in Oracle like this:

```
SELECT p.item_id, c.title
FROM product p
JOIN category c ON (p.item_id = c.item_id)
WHERE p.status = 'active';
```

This give me rows like this:

```
p.item_id | c.title
```

Now, let's say I have another table with tags, one tag per row, but I know that there are only two of them for every product. To make it clear:

```
title                     | item_id

'Some tag'                | 1
'Another tag'             | 1
'Tag for another product' | 2
```

And I need output like this:

```
p.item_id | c.title | t.tag_1 | t.tag_2
```

So in this case:

```
'Some product' | 'My category' | 'Some tag' | 'Another product'
```

When I join `tag` table, I don't know how to say that I want first result into one column and second into another. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have two, you can easily do this with `min()` and `max()`:

```
SELECT p.item_id, c.title, min(t.title) as tag1, max(t.title) as tag2
FROM product p JOIN
     category c
     ON p.item_id = c.item_id JOIN
     tags t
     ON p.item_id = t.item_id
WHERE p.status = 'active'
GROUP BY p.item_id, c.title;
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff have a good solution for you.
But, if you will have more than 2, you will need something bigger:

```
 select item, max(title1), ..., max(titleN) from (
 select item_id, 
 decode(nom, 1, title, null) title1,
 ....
 decode(nom, N, title, null) titleN
 from (
 select item_id, title, row_number() over (partition by item_id order by title) nom
 from category)
 )
```

Then join it to the product to get desired output.

If you need to run it not only in oracle, replace decode with CASE.